# spark-redshift works in pyspark shell but fails when using spark-submit

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift

Our cluster is running spark 2.0.1 which uses Scala 2.11.8

As per this doc: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

I should use:
    groupId: com.databricks
    artifactId: spark-redshift_2.11
    version: 3.0.0-preview1

I am able to query and write back to a table from

```
- spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1
- pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1
```

But if I run it from a pyspark script using spark-submit, I get the error below.

I run the spark submit with 
    **--packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1**

and I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RecordReaderIterator.<init>(RecordReaderIterator.scala:30)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(RedshiftFileFormat.scala:93)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.RedshiftFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(RedshiftFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more
```

Any idea why spark-submit is failing?

Comment: If you have spark installed on standalone (local) mode, please use the steps to run in your local and at later point dependencies can be substituted. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-spark/7372/calling-scala-from-java-program-a-simple-word-count-application-in-spark-2-0/24457/scala-environment-and-reference-libraries-without-maven#t=201704101936086657944

Comment: Spark is installed on the cluster (yarn), but I ran it in local mode.

Comment: Please add these jars in your ide build path and let know.

Comment: @PraveenKumarKrishnaiyer I already added the jars to spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath in /etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-defaults.conf Is there a different place I need to add the jar?

Comment: please check if the jar which you have added has previous versions. If yes, please replace with these jars alone. Also if you working on an IDE (like IntelliJ, eclipse), I would insist to add these jar files on the build path of the project.